# Pandas: Sort column by maximum values

Tags: sorting, pandas, max

Suppose we have following dataframe:

```
A  B  C  D

1  5  16 1
5  30 45 10
2  40 60 5
4  15 40 7
```

Here, we need to sort the columns according to their maximum values.
Accordingly, the columns should be sorted like:

```
C B D A
```

because max(C)=60, max(B)=40, max(D)=10, max(A)=5.

What's the best way to automate this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sort the result from `df.max` and use this to reindex the df:

```
In [64]:
df.ix[:, df.max().sort_values(ascending=False).index]

Out[64]:
    C   B   D  A
0  16   5   1  1
1  45  30  10  5
2  60  40   5  2
3  40  15   7  4
```

breaking the above down:

```
In [66]:
df.max()

Out[66]:
A     5
B    40
C    60
D    10
dtype: int64

In [67]:
df.max().sort_values(ascending=False)

Out[67]:
C    60
B    40
D    10
A     5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The good news is that it indeed sorts the lower ones to the back. Problem is though, that it shows C many more times? i.e. C C C C C C ... C B D A

Comment: Sorry what is the desired result here? Are you wanting to just sort the values row-wise? If so this is unclear and different to what you asked for

Comment: Until df.max().sort_values(ascending=False) it works well. It somehow break when creating the df(rearranging the columns)

Comment: Well it clearly works for me, you'll now need to post raw data, code to create your df, and the errors when using my code into your question